# Procedure with IN parameter having cursor

Tags: debugging, plsql, cursor

I have created a procedure to print the project details of an employee based on the input parameter `p_full_name` but it's not printing the details, instead going into the exception block. Can anyone please check and help me rectifying the error so that it prints the details of the employee.

Code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE project_details (p_full_name         IN     VARCHAR2,
                       p_name              OUT VARCHAR2,
                       p_status_code       OUT NUMBER,
                       p_project_type      OUT VARCHAR2,
                       p_start_date        OUT DATE,
                       p_end_date          OUT DATE)
IS
cursor c_project is
   SELECT  distinct xpppa.name Project_Name,
          pps.project_status_code ,
          xpppa.project_type ,
          xpppa.start_date,
          xpppa.completion_date
     FROM xxcas_prj_pa_projects_all xpppa,
          PA_PROJECT_STATUSES pps,
          XXCAS_PRJ_PA_PROJECT_PLAYERS xpppp,
          PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F papf
    WHERE     xpppa.project_status_code = pps.project_status_code
          AND xpppa.project_id = xpppp.project_id
          AND xpppp.person_id = papf.person_id
          AND papf.full_name=p_full_name--'Mahajan, Himani'
          AND xpppp.project_role_type = 'PROJECT MANAGER'
          AND pps.project_status_code IN ('1042', '1043')
          and papf.person_type_id=6
          and sysdate between xpppp.start_date_active and nvl(xpppp.end_date_active,sysdate+1) 
          and sysdate between papf.effective_start_date and nvl(papf.effective_end_date,sysdate+1);

          l_project_details c_project%rowtype;
begin
    open c_project;

    loop
        fetch c_project  into l_project_details;
        exit when c_project%NOTFOUND;
        debug( 'Project name: '||l_project_details.Project_Name
            ||' Project status code: '||l_project_details.Project_Status_Code
            ||' Project type: '||l_project_details.project_type
            ||' Project start date: '||l_project_details.start_date
            ||' Project end date: '||l_project_details.completion_date);
    end loop;

    close c_project;
exception
    when others then
        debug('Please provide valid input');
end project_details;
```

Comment: Is there any way you could get the actual error being thrown? Right now you handle all errors with the statement `WHEN OTHERS THEN`, but you aren't putting anything useful in the debug. Consider allowing the error to be thrown while testing, or at least debugging useful information like `SQLERRM`.

Comment: Also, consider using a cursor-for-loop; it'll simplify your code since you don't need to declare the variable to fetch into, nor do you have to open/fetch/exit/close the cursor explicitly; it's all handled in the cursor-for-loop for you. Plus, Oracle's compiler can optimise a cursor-for-loop behind the scenes for you, thus improving performance.

Comment: @Roly, can you please include a script on how you call the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

To debug, replace your last block with

```
exception
  when others then
    debug('error is:'||SQLERRM);
    debug('Project name :'||l_project_details.Project_Name
         ||' Project Status Code :'||l_project_details.Project_Status_Code
         ||'Project Type :'||l_project_details.project_type
         ||'Project start date :'||l_project_details.start_date
         ||'Project End Date : '||l_project_details.completion_date);
    --debug('Please provide valid input');
end project_details;
```

You^ll know more then.

Answer (score 1):

What is `DEBUG` in you code. I don't see `DEBUG` is correct to print something in `PLSQL`. Replace `DEBUG` with `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` if you want to print something. See below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROJECT_DETAILS (
     P_FULL_NAME      IN       VARCHAR2,
     P_NAME           OUT      VARCHAR2,
     P_STATUS_CODE    OUT      NUMBER,
     P_PROJECT_TYPE   OUT      VARCHAR2,
     P_START_DATE     OUT      DATE,
     P_END_DATE       OUT      DATE)
IS
     CURSOR C_PROJECT
     IS
          SELECT DISTINCT XPPPA.NAME PROJECT_NAME,
                          PPS.PROJECT_STATUS_CODE,
                          XPPPA.PROJECT_TYPE,
                          XPPPA.START_DATE,
                          XPPPA.COMPLETION_DATE
                     FROM XXCAS_PRJ_PA_PROJECTS_ALL XPPPA,
                          PA_PROJECT_STATUSES PPS,
                          XXCAS_PRJ_PA_PROJECT_PLAYERS XPPPP,
                          PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F PAPF
                    WHERE XPPPA.PROJECT_STATUS_CODE = PPS.PROJECT_STATUS_CODE
                          AND XPPPA.PROJECT_ID = XPPPP.PROJECT_ID
                          AND XPPPP.PERSON_ID = PAPF.PERSON_ID
                          AND PAPF.FULL_NAME = P_FULL_NAME --'Mahajan, Himani'
                          AND XPPPP.PROJECT_ROLE_TYPE = 'PROJECT MANAGER'
                          AND PPS.PROJECT_STATUS_CODE IN ('1042', '1043')
                          AND PAPF.PERSON_TYPE_ID = 6
                          AND SYSDATE BETWEEN XPPPP.START_DATE_ACTIVE
                                          AND NVL (XPPPP.END_DATE_ACTIVE,
                                                   SYSDATE + 1)
                          AND SYSDATE BETWEEN PAPF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
                                          AND NVL (PAPF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
                                                   SYSDATE + 1);

     L_PROJECT_DETAILS             C_PROJECT%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
     OPEN C_PROJECT;

     LOOP
          FETCH C_PROJECT
           INTO L_PROJECT_DETAILS;

          EXIT WHEN C_PROJECT%NOTFOUND;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (   'Project name :'
                                || L_PROJECT_DETAILS.PROJECT_NAME
                                || ' Project Status Code :'
                                || L_PROJECT_DETAILS.PROJECT_STATUS_CODE
                                || 'Project Type :'
                                || L_PROJECT_DETAILS.PROJECT_TYPE
                                || 'Project start date :'
                                || L_PROJECT_DETAILS.START_DATE
                                || 'Project End Date : '
                                || L_PROJECT_DETAILS.COMPLETION_DATE);
     END LOOP;

     CLOSE C_PROJECT;
EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Please provide valid input');
END PROJECT_DETAILS;
```

Note to use correct exception handler as DBMS_OUTPUT will not raise any issue rather it would simply display message and complete procedure successfully.